Sequelize SQLite Delete Not Working - Table Not Found Error
I have a React+Node Web app, and I cant't figure out why the delete is not working, Create, Read, Update work well, I have tested with Postman
The error I get is:(put the one from the server)
SQLITE_ERROR: no such table: main.product 
the error in server terminal
This is my delete function from my controller

exports.deleteProduct = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const products = await Product.findByPk(req.params.id);
        if (!products) {
            res.status(404).send("Product not found");
            return;
        }

        if (products.imageUrl) {
            const imagePath = path.join(__dirname, "..", products.imageUrl);
            fs.unlink(imagePath, (err) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.error("Failed to delete the image file:", err);
                }
            });
        }

        await products.destroy();
        res.status(204).send("Product deleted");
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Failed to delete product:", error);
        res.status(500).send(error.message);
    }
};


This is my Product Model
const { Model, DataTypes } = require("sequelize");

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    class Product extends Model {}

    Product.init(
        {
            name: {
                type: DataTypes.STRING,
                allowNull: false,
            },
            description: {
                type: DataTypes.TEXT,
                allowNull: true,
            },
            price: {
                type: DataTypes.FLOAT,
                allowNull: false,
                validate: {
                    isFloat: true,
                },
            },
            category: {
                type: DataTypes.STRING,
                allowNull: false,
            },
            imageUrl: {
                type: DataTypes.STRING,
                allowNull: true,
            },
        },
        {
            sequelize,
            modelName: "Product",
            tableName: "products",
            freezeTableName: true,
            timestamps: false,
        }
    );

    return Product;
};

And here are the routes

``const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const productController = require("../controllers/productController");
const upload = require("../config/uploadConfig");

router.get("/", productController.getAllProducts);
router.post("/add", upload.single("image"), productController.createProduct);
router.get("/:id", productController.getProductById);
router.put("/:id", productController.updateProduct);
router.delete("/:id", productController.deleteProduct);

module.exports = router;`
`

The Delete Function
Postman Request
I did rewrite the functions multiple times, i remaked the Model, I can't wrap my mind around the fact that it says the table isnt found but the other functions work...
